# apache server-status 403 forbidden azure centos vm

Tags: centos, apache-httpd

I get 403 forbidden for http://testapache.cloudapp.net/server-status. Below are the following exact steps I have followed.

- I created a new centos vm.
- Then ran yum install httpd
- Opened /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf using vi editor
- `LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so`
  was not in httpd.conf I added it manually

  - then added location directive since it was not available in commented state. I have given permission so everyone can access.

`<Location /server-status>`
    `SetHandler server-status
       Order allow,deny
       Deny from all
       Allow from all`
`</Location>`

- also added  `ExtendedStatus On`
- then ran httpd restart

Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) Server built: Aug 24 2015 18:11:25

Am I missing any step I was following steps in this link http://www.tecmint.com/monitor-apache-web-server-load-and-page-statistics/

Comment: Access control commands have changed from httpd 2.2 to httpd 2.4. Since you're not restricting anything anyway right now, can you try removing the `Order`/`Deny`/`Allow` lines altogether?

Comment: thanks that worked! but how do we manage restrictions now in 2.4